# TAL Code for getting list of values from py file to TAL Portlet

Tags: plone

How do I get a list of values from a filesystem Python file into a TAL Portlet (made available by `collective.portlet.tal`)?

My TAL code looks like this:

```
<div tal:define="address_view context/@@address_view" >
    <span tal:define="global li address_view/createPictMenu">   
      <span tal:re?lace="structure python:li[3]" />
    </span>
</div>
```

When I tried to run the code I got an `Invalid variable name li` error. What is the right syntax for that?

Comment: Have you tried another variable name?

Comment: Why does `li` need to be global at all?

Comment: As I've already told you: Stop using collective.portlet.tal. It doesn’t do what you want or expect, and is only giving you a lot of extra problems that you would not have if you weren't using it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use a global variable, preface it with `global`, otherwise TAL won't find it:

```
<div tal:define="address_view context/@@address_view" >
    <span tal:define="global li address_view/createPictMenu">   
      <span tal:re?lace="structure python: global li[3]" />
    </span>
</div>
```

Or alternatively, don't use global at all:

```
<div tal:define="address_view context/@@address_view" >
  <span tal:define="li address_view/createPictMenu">   
    <span tal:re?lace="structure python:li[3]" />
   </span>
</div>
```

Comment: thank q for ur replay if i use class bdrMenuView(Logoviewlet,BrowserView):means i got__init__taken 4 but 5 given eror .so i delete logo viewlet  arguments means its worked so how can i get alue from multi argument class